# Linq to Entites has-many-through

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-entities

Greetings -

I could use some with creating a linq to entities statement that would include all my models. I have three models: Alumni, Logs and LogTypes. An Alumnus may have many Logs and Logs may have one LogType. If I want the alumnus with the logs I would say:

```
Alumnus alumnus = _entities.Alumni.Include("Logs").FirstOrDefault(a = > a.Id = Id);
```

Works fine, but it does not include the LogType. I thought that .Include("Logs.LogTypes") would do the trick, but it does not. How would I include the LogType? Below is a quick snip of the models:

```
Alumni
-------
Id
FirstName
LastName

Logs
-------
Id
AlumnusId
LogTypeId
LoggedOn
Detail

LogTypes
---------
Id
Type
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that EF didn't singularize LogTypes? What is the name of the property on one of your Log objects? If it is just "LogType", then you need `Include("Logs.LogType")`

Comment: werks! Thanks man! I knew is was simple; just wasn't seeing it.